# How to display graph from database values using php?

Tags: php, graph

I want to create graph using php. I have tested jpgraph example. But it display error
like

```
> The image “http://localhost/test/jpgraphtest.php” cannot be displayed
> because it contains errors.

<?php
include('phpgraphlib.php');
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(500,350);
$data = array(12124, 5535, 43373, 22223, 90432, 23332, 15544, 24523,
 32778, 38878, 28787, 33243, 34832, 32302);
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle('Widgets Produced');
$graph->setGradient('red', 'maroon');
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

Comment: what the problem ? that file has error solve those error i mean this question is vague show relevant error and source code

Answer (score 2):

check this link I think its perfect.

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

(also you should configure php to enable image creating).
In Windows, you'll include the GD2 DLL php_gd2.dll as an extension in php.ini. The GD1 DLL php_gd.dll was removed in PHP 4.3.2. Also note that the preferred truecolor image functions, such as imagecreatetruecolor(), require GD2.

check these links.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.requirements.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.configuration.php
examples:

[image: ex01]

[image: ex02]

Comment: @swapnesh I had hear about it very much.is it now clear why its perfect?

Comment: I also tried example in above link but it has also same error.

Comment: ok I think the problem is with graphic extension in php that you should enable it.

Comment: how to enable it?please tell me

Comment: check link in my answer. `In Windows, you'll include the GD2 DLL php_gd2.dll as an extension in php.ini. The GD1 DLL php_gd.dll was removed in PHP 4.3.2. Also note that the preferred truecolor image functions, such as imagecreatetruecolor(), require GD2. `

Comment: i am afraid that its link only answer ... and will be remove so add some information why code in question is not working and why this will work